# C++ standard - how "array of unknown bound of T" is treated

Tags: c++, arrays, standards

I've got confused by the fact that this code works:

```
struct S
{
  char c[];
};
S s;
```

According to C++ standard, chapter 8.3.4:

> "If the constant
>   expression is omitted, the type of the
>   identifier of D is
>   “derived-declarator-type-list array of
>   unknown bound of T”, an incomplete
>   object type."

But I cannot figure out how "incomplete object type" becomes complete.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Welcome to SO, while asking the question you can use the buttons at the top (1010, etc) to format the code and quote parts your question correctly.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717671/static-arrays-defined-with-unspecified-size-empty-brackets

Comment: Great link. According to one of answers it should not compile. I've tried my code on gcc 4.4.4 (-ansi) and VC2010 and both compiled.

Comment: Try `-pedantic` as well as `-ansi` in GCC - it leaves a lot of language extensions enabled that don't conflict with valid C++, if you don't specify `-pedantic`.

Comment: Gcc with -pedantic gives a warning of "zero sized array", but compiles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've said the code you posted will compile in VS10.  Turn off language extensions, and then it won't.  Project>Properties>C/C++>Language>Disable Language Extensions = Yes.  This is compiling because you are using a MS-specific extension to the C++ language.

In short, according to the standard, your code should not compile.

Comment: "When an array is used as the type of a nonstatic member all dimensions shall be specified." (9.2/8)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this language feature is invented in order to allow the array to be initialized later in the source file. If I make `c` non-static, then at least on Visual Studio 2010 it fails to compile, saying that the length of `c` has been fixed at 0, and member redeclaration is not allowed.

```
// header file
struct S
{
    static char c[];
    static size_t len;
};
extern S s;

// source file
char S::c[] = "haha";
size_t S::len = (sizeof(S::c) / sizeof(S::c[0])) - 1;
```