# Allocating memory to pointer multidimensional array with new

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, new-operator

I can't understand some basic thing in c++ and have been wondering. Please help me.
I understand that p points to memory that would be a 2D int matrix of 3x4 size.

```
int(*p)[3][4];
```

1) Why can't I allocate memory like following?

```
p = new int[3][4];
```

2) It should be like following to work. But why?

```
p = new int [1][3][4];    //or new int [5][3][4]; etc
```

3) What does following line of code mean? It is semantically correct but what is it doing? What is significance of empty [] in following line?

```
p = new int [ ][3][4];
```

Comment: @Muscampester 
No, I do not add anything

Answer (score 2):

c++ is a strongly typed language. `int` is not the same as `int*`. Likewise `int[3]` is not the same type as `int*`. But just lightly poke `int[3]` with a stick and it will fall apart and decay to an `int*`. c++ does this because c does it.

---

> Why can't I allocate memory like following?
>
> ```
> p = new int[3][4];
> ```

Because the `new` is returning a pointer to `int[4]`:

```
auto p1 = new int[3][4]; // int(*p1)[4]
```

The array has [decayed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14183554/1460794) to a pointer. It has [lost the type and first dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1461449/1460794). It would be best to avoid pointers for arrays and stick to [using templates and references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17569578/1460794). Or better yet, prefer `std::vector` or `std::array`.

You could have multiple pointers to the same address, [but with different types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12674201/1460794), which [can be confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22984784/1460794).

---

> 2) It should be like following to work. But why?
>
> ```
> p = new int [1][3][4];
> ```

In this example the array of `int[3][4]`s has also decayed to a pointer:

```
auto p2 = new int [1][3][4]; // int(*p2)[3][4]
```

So here the value returned by `new` can be assigned to `p` because it has the same type. Note however that the pointer type doesn't include information about the size of the array, it only has a type that points to elements which happen to be arrays of a lower dimension (that haven't decayed to pointers).

---

> 3) What does following line of code mean? It is semantically correct
>   but what is it doing? What is significance of empty [] in following
>   line?
>
> ```
> p = new int [ ][3][4];
> ```

This might not always compile, and if it does then it is a [compiler extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2717851/1460794) that will determine the value of the empty square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Because in C, "int *p" has two interpretations.
You can consider P to be a pointer to a single integer, but it can also be considered to be a pointer to an array of integer.

A common example, strings.
char *a = "hello";

"a" is a pointer to a single character, 'h', but more commonly it is treated as a pointer to an array of characters, aka a string.

So, you can do this:
    char * a = new char[6];
    strcpy(a, "hello");

I believe that your third example is not valid C++.

While this:
   p = new int [9][3][4];
Allocates an array of 9 two dimensional arrays of 3x4.

Try this test:

```
int test()
{
    int(* p)[3][4] = new int[1][3][4];

    printf("sizeof(p)=%d, sizeof(*p)=%d\n", sizeof(p), sizeof(*p) / sizeof(int));

    size_t q1 = (size_t)&p[0][0][0];
    size_t q2 = (size_t)&p[1][0][0];
    printf("p, diff: %d\n", (q2 - q1) / sizeof(int));

    size_t r1 = (size_t)&p[0][0][0];
    size_t r2 = (size_t)&p[0][1][0];
    printf("p, diff: %d\n", (r2 - r1) / sizeof(int));

    size_t s1 = (size_t)&p[0][0][0];
    size_t s2 = (size_t)&p[0][0][1];
    printf("p, diff: %d\n", (s2 - s1) / sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}
```